# How to access, open and read email using Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I'm newer in Alfresco and Activiti, and I looking for a way how to access, open and read the content of an incoming mail using the Alfresco's API, like as javax.mail API. It's possible, or I have to do by another way?

Comment: I expect to open the mail, extract the body and search for some text patterns in its content

Answer (score 2):

To get the incoming email in alfresco you need to configure Inbound email system in your alfresco.

Inbound is supported by alfresco and allows user to send email with attachment to alfresco.

Alfresco even though it supports inbound emails this feature is not enabled by default, in order to enable it you have to set this parameters into your alfresco global properties file

> tomcat/shared/alfresco-global.properties

```
email.server.enabled=true
```

This next few properties are optional

```
email.server.port=25 #specify your port if this one is taken
email.inbound.unknownUser=anonymous  
email.server.domain=localhost #specify your domain
```

please refer this [documentation](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/email-inboundsmtp-props.html) for more information

Comment: My question is more specific. I expect to open the mail, extract the body and search  for some text patterns in its content

Comment: No, There no  feature default Out of the box in alfresco